# Removing the (www) for subdomains

Tags: php, .htaccess, dns, subdomain

I created a new subdomain for my site.

http://www.catalog.modifit9plus1.com. But i can only access the site using this form. How do i make it accessible via http://catalog.modifit9plus1.com?

Comment: It has something to do with your domain provider and DNS fields (look for CNAME).

Comment: That depends on what's keeping you from doing so now. Are the DNS records configured correctly? Is the web server configured correctly?

Comment: for me it is already accessible via http://catalog.modifit9plus1.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Theolodis @Lawrence

I can also access using either link. Could this not be a browser problem?

EDIT:
I am pretty sure I have seen some old browsers not being able to load URLs lacking the 'www' prefix. An old version of Epiphany maybe. I can't find anything backing this up on the Internet though.

Comment: Ha. I'm using chrome. Guess i forgot the most basic oversight of them all, I forgot to flush my browsing cache.